# Facebook login failure using Angular, and Google Firebase - INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE: Error getting access token from facebook.com

Tags: angular, firebase, facebook, facebook-login

I am developing [a basic web app](https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/login) to measure some political popularity. To get correct polls, we gonna need to authenticate users with their social media accounts such as Facebook, Twitter, and Google accounts.

I have selected Angular as my front-end technology which sits on [Google Firebase platform](https://firebase.google.com/) which come to following [this instruction](https://www.positronx.io/firebase-facebook-login-auth-provider-work-with-angular/) to make authentications.

For Firebase Facebook Login Auth Provider Service (`auth.service.ts`)

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
) { }

// Sign in with Facebook
FacebookAuth() {
   return this.AuthLogin(new auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
}  

// Auth logic to run auth providers
AuthLogin(provider) {
   return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
     .then((result) => {
         console.log('You have been successfully logged in!')
     }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
   }
}
```

for the singin component codes is as simple as following

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../shared/services/auth.service";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-sign-in',
   templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})

export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
   ngOnInit() { }
```

}

HTML codes for `singin components`

```
<!-- Calling FacebookAuth Api from AuthService -->
<div class="formGroup">
   <button type="button" (click)="authService.FacebookAuth()">
      Log in with Facebook
   </button>
</div>
```

Here is the **configuration on Facebook for developer**.

- `App ID`, and `App Secret` are put in Firebase to make the connection between two.
- In facebook login > settings : `client Oauth login`, `web OAuth login` are on
  and and added these URLs for redirect (taken from Firebase facebook enabling login popup)
- settings > Basics > Site URL is: `https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/`

What am I missing to get ride of following error?

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 400,
   "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from facebook.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=OAuthException&error_description=This%20IP%20can't%20make%20requests%20for%20that%20application., httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n, contentSecurityPolicies=[], cookieList=[]}}",
  "errors": [
     {
       "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from facebook.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=OAuthException&error_description=This%20IP%20can't%20make%20requests%20for%20that%20application., httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n, contentSecurityPolicies=[], cookieList=[]}}",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "invalid"
    }
  ]
 }
```

}

BTW app is working on Google login, you can see that redirect URL is `https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/profile`

Comment: `error_description=This%20IP%20can't%20make%20requests%20for%20that%20application.` sounds like you might made have `Server IP Whitelist` entries that do not match the actual IPs the request is made from …?

Comment: @CBroe: yes sir. You are correct, Yesterday, I was able to find the reason, and reason was exactly what you are saying

Comment: @CBroe It's correct, same error and after removing the IP it worked!, thanks!